# ¿Como puedo recibir una fecha de un formulario html en net core?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo un formulario realizado en una pagina Html al enviarlo al controlador, marca un error porque la fecha la recibe como un string y yo la tengo declarada en el modelo como un tipo DateTime.

¿Existe una forma de recibir la fecha con el tipo de dato especificado, sin modificar el modelo a string?

Error:
[image: este es error que me indica.]

Formulario:

```
<form action="nuevo/planestudios" method="post" class="container-fluid">
    <section class="row container">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Plan 1">
            <small id="nombre" class="form-text text-muted">Ingrese el nombre del plan de estudio</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha inicio</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="01/01/2019">
            <small id="fechaInicio" class="form-text text-muted">Ingresela feha de inicio</small>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
    </section>
</form>
```

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("nuevo/planestudios")]
public IActionResult Nuevo(TblPlanEstudio tblPlanEstudio )
{
    TblPlanEstudiosService tblPlanEstudiosService = new TblPlanEstudiosService();

    tblPlanEstudiosService.Insertar(tblPlanEstudio);
    return RedirectToAction("index"); 
}
```

Modelo:

```
public class TblPlanEstudio{
      [Key]
      public int Id{get; set;}
      [StringLength(20)]
      public string nombre {get; set;}
      [StringLength(50)]
      public DateTime fechaInicio{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar que error en especifico te marca?

Comment: Listo amigo, adjunte una captura del error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solamente elimina el stringlength de tu propiedad datetime, no puedes meterle este atributo a la propiedad de tipo datetime

```
public class TblPlanEstudio{
      [Key]
      public int Id{get; set;}
      [StringLength(20)]
      public string nombre {get; set;}

      public DateTime fechaInicio{get; set;}

    }
```

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias.